# how to have modals in Vue.js app l

Tags: vuejs2

I am migrating a jQuery app to Vuejs2. I really like Vue but am not sure what the best way to have a modal component would be (I'm using Bootstrap4 for css and modal components). I'd like to do something like this:

```
    addMore: function(){
       alert("adding more");
       var html = HandlebarsTemplates['vendors/pricings/dashboard/modals/change-pricing-model']();
       $('.modal-content').html(html);
       $('#myModal').modal('show')
    },
```

and have:

```
<div v-on:click="addMore">add more</div>
```

but, to the best of my knowledge, this doesn't work. What is the standard pattern for having modals in a Vue app (preferabley using Bootstrap)?

Comment: https://github.com/Coffcer/vue-bootstrap-modal  this might inspire you

Comment: try this: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

Comment: I would look at what @drinor recommended and style your Vuejs modal's content with Bootstrap.